# How to add event on all label in nested div in angular or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i want to add event all label in html.in my code just event occur on first label. how to solve it?
here is sample of my code:

```
<div id="accordion">
      <label class="label">{{}}</label>  // just this label event run
      <div>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="l in list" class="loop">
          <div ng-if="" class="if">
          <label class="label">{{}}</label>
          <div class="div">
              <p> {{}}</p>
          </div>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

and my jquery code is

```
   $(".label").click(function(){
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion .div').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Yet another event-delegation-related question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code . instead of '.label' use tag name 'label'. it will assign all 'label' tag click event using jquery .  see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dddhh80x/)

```
$(document).on('click',"label",function(){
   if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('#accordion .div').slideUp(300);
   }
   $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add events to all labels presents in the HTML, by selecting the label like : -
    $('label').on('click', (function(){
    //do something
    }))